# How to inject a new variable into a menu template

Tags: 8, theming, hooks, bootstrap-theme

I have a menu with a machine name of `menu-principal`, which in turn has a theme hook of `menu__menu_principal` and a template of `menu--menu-principal.html.twig`. I'm trying to inject another menu into the template in a variable so that I can render it in this menu template but so far have been unsuccessful.

I tried to add a preprocess function to my `MY_THEME.theme` but this doesn't seem to work. My code is as follows:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_menu__menu_principal(&$variables) {
  $menu_tree_service = \Drupal::service('menu.link_tree');
  $menu_name = 'menu-quicklinks';
  $menu_parameters = new \Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuTreeParameters();
  $tree = $menu_tree_service->load($menu_name, $menu_parameters);
  $variables['quicklinks'] = $tree;
}
```

When I go to to the template and use `{{ kint() }}` to dump out the defined variables, I don't see the variable. I only see the following:

[image: {{ kint() }} output in menu--menu-principal.html.twig]

I then found [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/247187/adding-more-variables-to-menu-for-use-in-menu-html-twig) and tried the following, using the example from the answer there:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function MY_THEME_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['menu__menu_principal']['variables']['quicklinks'] = [];
}
```

I used `dd()` to verify that `$theme_registry['menu__menu_principal']['variables']` existed and that the variables were definitely being set in the theme registry, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Your hook preprocess won't get called. Preprocess hook names don't work like templates with interpolated suggestions. Call the function MYTHEME_preprocess_menu and add a test in it for the menu you want.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong Thanks for the suggestion, I will try that. It’s strange that I get `{{ kint () }}` output for it, though, so it does seem to fire. It perhaps just doesn’t do anything.

Comment: Name suggestions do work for templates, so your specific template is called, just not for preprocess functions.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, but i was using `{{ dump() }}` to debug the template

### The problem

I have the same arguments when i am using `{{ dump() }}` inside macro tags. For example:

```
   {% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level ) %}
       {{ dump() }}
       ... code ...
   {% endmacro %}
```

If you focus on function `menu_links()`, you realize that variables are available in your degug trace. So, the macro tags have isolated the bunch of code and variables can't be accessed.

### The solution

If you place the debug code outside of macro tags, you can see the variables that has been passed throught a preproccess function. For example:

```
   # You can see here your variables
   {{ dump() }}

   {% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level ) %}
       ... code ...
   {% endmacro %}
```

**How can you pass variables to macro ?**

There are an invocation of `menu_links()` in template, so you only need to add all the arguments you want to pass them to the macro.

```
   {{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0, my_custom_argument ) }}

   {% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level, my_custom_argument ) %}
       ... code ...
   {% endmacro %}
```