# Pass a value from a block preprocess hook to a twig template that inserts that block

Tags: 8, theming

I use the D8 `book` module to manage magazines and their articles.

In the `node--magazine.html.twig` template for a magazine, I use the built-in `book_navigation` block to add a table of contents. This is done by `drupal_block("book_navigation", {block_mode: "book pages"})`. Works fine.

For certain "featured" articles in the table of contents, I want to display an image. I use `MYTHEME_preprocess_book_tree(&$variables)` to add the image url to the `items` array in $variables. I've sub-themed `book-tree-html.twig` to get the image url from the `items` array and include the image in the table of contents. Works fine.

BUT, I need to know in `node--magazine.html.twig` whether there are any featured articles in the table of contents to present a proper heading on the page.

QUESTION: What is the best way to pass a variable from `THEME_preprocess_book_tree()` to `node--magazine.html.twig`? It's not a direct connection. Getting preprocess variables in `book-tree.html.twig` is easy, but I need to pass a variable through to `node--magazine.html.twig`, where the book tree is inserted.

What I have tried:

- In the `book-tree.html.twig` template, if there is a featured article, I add a hidden "featured-article" label to the html and then in the magazine template, I test for its presence via `{% if "featured-article" in <rendered block html> %}`. This works, but it feels unsavory.
- In `MYTHEME_preprocess_book_tree()`, I add `$variables['featured'] = $feature_count;` and in the magazine template I `{{ dump(featured) }}`. This doesn't work. I just get NULL. I'm not sure what--if any--connection there is between the $variables array available in the preprocess hook and variables available in the magazine template.
- In `MYTHEME_preprocess_book_tree()`, I could set a global variable and then in the magazine template, call a custom twig extension to check the value of that variable. I haven't tried this yet, but it seems like this should work. Just seems like there should be a more elegant way.

Comment: the `book-tree.html.twig` uses macro similar to `menu.html.twig`. see [Adding more variables to menu for use in menu.html.twig](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/247187/adding-more-variables-to-menu-for-use-in-menu-html-twig)

Comment: I think your second approach should work. If you are preprocessing in `THEME_preprocess_book_tree`, your `$variables` array should be available for use in `book-tree.html.twig`. If your preprocess function is otherwise working for this template, are you sure the issue isn't with `dump()`? That sounds silly, but I've had issues with it. Have you tried just setting the values and checking if that works? Does the `$variables` array from that preprocess function otherwise work? Just trying to figure out where the issue is coming from here.

Comment: Thanks @usernameabc. I read the post and tried everything I could think of, but no success. The situation may be different in that I have a value in the preprocess function for the `book_navigation` block and I want to get that value--not in the twig template for the `book_navigation` block--but in a twig template into which the book_navigation block is inserted. I just can't seem to find a connection between the $variables array available in the `book_navigation` preprocess hook and the array of values that is available in the template where the block is inserted.

Comment: Thanks, @burke626. I can get variables set in `THEME_preprocess_book_tree` just fine in `book-tree.html.twig`. Unfortunately, that's not where I need to know if there was at least one featured article. I need to know that in the node--magazine.html.twig template, into which I insert the `book_navigation` block via {% `drupal_block("book_navigation", {block_mode: "book pages"}) %}`.I'll edit my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot more digging and trying things without success, I ended up solving the problem of passing a value from a block's preprocess hook to a twig template where the block is inserted as per my third option above. Here's what I did:

- Follow the instructions at `http://www.tothenew.com/blog/overview-of-twig-extentions-in-drupal-8` to create a twig extension. This wasn't very difficult, especially since I had already created a custom module. I just had to create a `MYMODULE.services.yml` file and a `TwigExtension.php` file as instructed.
- In the twig extension file, create functions `setTwigValue($name, $value)` and `getTwigValue($name)` using the php $GLOBALS array for storage. Again, the above-mentioned instructions made this pretty easy.
- In the preprocess_book_tree hook, count the number of feature articles and then save the count by calling

  `Drupal\MYMODULE\TwigExtension::setTwigValue('feature_count', $feature_count);`
- In the node--magazine.html.twig template, get the saved value using

  `{% set feature_count = getTwigValue('feature_count') %}`

I'm happy to learn of better/safer ways to accomplish what I've done. But at least it works and it's pretty clean.